# Programming/running a NXT brick with a dead screen, via PC?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

I have a NXT set and the control brick has a dead screen. I tried fixing it (resoldered caps, ribbon rub, etc) to no avail. It's dead.

Is there any software that will allow me to program and execute code on the NXT brick without going through the screen options? Is there a way to see the screen on a PC?

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool called NeXTScreen that is available [here](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/utilities.html) that will let you see the screen (and remotely control the NXT). There are similar tools for OS X and Linux on the same page.

Once you have this setup, you should be able to use any programming environment that you like. The screen viewing programs should be able to run at the same time as anything else.

For example, you could use the screen viewing program to pair via Bluetooth, then program the NXT using NXT-G and use use the "run" button in NXT-G to start the program remotely.

Comment: I tried the NeXTScreen, it was not able to connect to the brick. I then tried to upload a new firmware via the Lego software, and it just got stuck and bricked the brick. Now all it does is click. I tried holding the reset button, no change. It doesn't register in the Lego software so I can't upload a new firmware. I think this is the end. I think it's time to make my own Arduino-based control brick.

Comment: It sounds like your brick may have more problems than just the screen. However, if you have Arduino software installed on your computer, it could be interfering with the USB driver. See http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/lego-mindstorms-nxt-bossa-driver-prevents-firmware-upgrade

Comment: Thanks! I was able to reflash the firmware. The NeXTScreen still doesn't work though. Should I choose usb as the port?

Comment: Yes, you will need to use USB as the port for NeXTScreen to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

My kids and I are having a blast controlling old NXT bricks with a few Android apps, via Bluetooth, and it all works like a charm!!!
 App links below:

I have 4 NXT bricks, but only one has a working screen.  If you hold two units side-by-side, you can navigate to Bluetooth and enable. 
Or follow the steps below:  Note: (Enter = orange button)

1. Turn on your NXT brick, "cool Mindstorm chime!!!"
2. Left button, (3) times, to "Bluetooth", press enter
3. Let button, (1) time, to Search, press enter
4. Searching.........let it ride for like (30) seconds
5. Press enter, to select your (one), Bluetooth enabled smartphone
6. Press enter again, to select slot one "cool passkey: chime"
7. Press enter once more, to select "1234" as your passkey
8. Finally, hop over to your smartphone & pair to "NXT" with that key

NXTpad: let's you see and execute programs on the brick, + more
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_bccyuen.NXTPad

NXTremotecontrol: let's you control your builds like a TANK!!!!
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jfedor.nxtremotecontrol